# react event.target.value for date

Tags: reactjs

With `react-calender` component on an onBlur event if I print

```
console.log("event.target",event.target)
```

it is printing `event.target` as

```
 <input type=​"text" value=​"05/​02/​2018">​`
```

when i print type of that component

```
console.log("event.target.type",event.target.type)
```

it is printing `event.target.type` as `text`

but when i tried to print value of date component  `console.log("event.target.value",event.target.value)` it is giving "". Why target.value is not printing date..?

Answer (score 0):

From  [`docs#react-calender`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar).

Please user `Calender` Component.

```
state = {
  date: new Date()
}

render() {
  return (<Calendar onChange={(date) => this.setState({date})} value={this.state.date}/>);
}
```